Constant current feedback op-amp analysis

Above is the schematic for the convoy XHP35 flashlight driver. As you can see, the current control loop uses the op-amp as a comparator between a setpoint (low-pass filtered PWM output from a microcontroller) and the current sense resistor shunt voltage. The output pulls the MP3431 FB pin to GND or 2.5 V through a 100 kΩ resistor.
The part I don't understand are the two resistors at the FB pin of the MP3431 that are connected to Vout and Gnd. Without the op-amp, that would have made a voltage divider for a constant voltage controller. But what purpose do those serve in stability and output current regulation of the converter?
EDIT:
As compared to using a simple current sense amplifier into FB pin as below:

Hence, what really is the point of 100k, 470k, and 47k in the first image?

As you say, they are used to set a fixed voltage. With the opamp you "hack" in on the feedback and can adjust or set the output voltage on the fly.

@Tyassin, so are you saying the 470k  and theand 47k are unneeded, then? How do you use those two resistors opamp to calculate the voltage seen at FB? I can't wrap my head around that.

Well not quite. The swicth controller is operating in closed loop, so it will try and maintain the FB pin at 1V. The Opamp is configured in openloop, not the best thing, and the output will go from rail-to-rail. But you have to notice the 100K ohm resistor at the output of the Opamp. This is pulling in the FB pin and thereby the output voltage from MP3431.
By quick analysis then if the opamp output is high, then it would like to pull the FB higher, but the MP3431 will then adjust its output down until it is 1V.
And the other way around if the opamp output is low.

@Tyassin It's fair enough to say that I'm even more confused. Can you describe that further in an answer? Parts I didn't quite catch: "100k resistor...pulling in the FB pin". I only see that the 100k resistor pulls the opamp output to ground or 2.5V. I don't understand how the FB pin is pulled higher or lower based on output. Also, there was no mention of the 470 and 40k resistors.

In the schematic the output of the opamp is connected to a 100K ohm which is connected to FB.

Yea, i can see that, but it's not just the opamp output with 100k that's connected to FB

Refer to the alternative approach (edit) without 470k, 47k, and 100k, which makes more sense.
